# Is it possible to use hasAnyRole() and @RolesAllowed interchangeably in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two methods under the same Controller class - one is for a public endpoint and the other for the authorized users.

```
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity public() {...}

    @GetMapping("/internal/endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity internal() {...}

}
```

And in the Security Configuration, I have:

```
http
   .csrf().disable()
   .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
   .and()
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
   .antMatchers("/internal/**").authenticated()
```

If I add `@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_A", "ROLE_B"})` to the `internal()` method I get a 403 for the roles that are not allowed. But If I remove that and add `.antMatchers("/internal/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_A", "ROLE_B")` to the security configuration it allows the users with unauthorized roles to access the internal endpoints.

My question is - can I use them interchangeably? If yes, what am I missing? Since I have quite a few internal endpoints I would prefer to have the role check in the security configuration rather that adding `@RolesAllowed` to every internal method, but I am also open to follow the best practice.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my issue. I tried with multiple combinations like -

".antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/internal/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_A", "ROLE_B")"
but didn't work

Comment: The first rule that matches is applied. Because `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` is first, it is applied and subsequent rules are ignored.

Comment: I tried with `.antMatchers("/internal/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_A", "ROLE_B").antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`, I get 403 for both roles allowed and not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using `.hasAnyRole("ROLE_A", "ROLE_B")` as opposed to `.hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_A", "ROLE_B")`, it was not working. I had to use `.hasAnyRole("A", "B")` to get it to work. The `ROLE_` prefix gets added to the values automatically. So my working config is

```java
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/internal/**").hasAnyRole("A", "B")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```